# User Regex in java to find phrases

Tags: java, regex

Hi I am trying to discover phrases in a string using regex I have the following code: it does not seem to find all the two word phrases.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputText = "test and test Test hello hello hello test test hello hello ";

    //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((\\w{3,}?)\\W(\\w{3,}?)\\W).*\\2\\W\\3", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    Pattern twoWordPrasePattern = Pattern.compile("(([a-zA-Z]{3,})\\W([a-zA-Z]{3,})\\W).*\\2\\W\\3", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    Matcher matcher = twoWordPrasePattern.matcher(inputText);       
    while (matcher.find()) {

        System.out.println(inputText.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));

        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));

    }

}
```

I am struggling with this why does the hello hello group not get out put?
Any help appreciated thanks. how can I change the pattern to find all the phrases? Richard

Answer (score 3):

`matcher.find()` always searches from where the previous match left off. The first call finds this:

```
test Test hello hello hello test test
```

so all that's left to search in is the

```
hello hello
```

at the end. That final `hello hello` doesn't match your pattern (since it only has two words, and your pattern requires at least four words: it grabs two words as groups `2` and `3`, and then finds `\2\W\3` later on), so it doesn't get output.

Comment: Thanks ruakh, that explain that now how can I change the pattern to find all the phrases